# Como entrar com um numero (x) e fazer a soma de todos os números anteriores?

Tags: javascript, for, programação-funcional

Como entrar com um número e fazer a soma de todos os números anteriores, EXEMPLO: entro com o número 5, ele ira somar 0+1+2+3+4 = 10 ! Ele irá somar e dar a resposta.

Tenho que usar o comando FOR.

O meu comando ficou assim, mas não está correto.

```
function somatoria(x){
  var soma = 0;

  for(var i = 0;  i < x;  i++) {
  soma = i +  i;}

  return soma;
}
```

Comment: Tenta `soma += i`

Comment: `soma = soma + i;` ou, simplificando, `soma += i`

Comment: A única diferença pra essa aí é que lá vai de 2 em 2 e aqui vai em 1, o que nessa parte já está certo.

Comment: deu certo galera, de tanto que mexi o código, dei esse vacilo, mais obrigadao, gente.

Comment: Só não faz sentido iniciar a variável `i` do laço com `0`, já que 0 não altera o resultado. Então poderia ser `var i = 1`.

Comment: function somatoria(x){
  var soma = 0;

  for(var i = 0;  i < x;  i++) {
  soma = soma +  i;}

return soma;
}